# iOS Enterprise provisioning profile distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, profile, enterprise

I am signing a dylib in my application with an Enterprise certificate and noticed that on some devices I get the following error:

```
0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
```

The strange thing is on the devices where this works I never manually installed a provisioning profile. I think when I used XCode it got automated installed somehow.

Manually installing the 'Distribution in house' profile associated with the cert on these devices fixed the problem, but I'm trying to understand how to deploy my software without requiring this extra step.

What is the standard way of pushing out the enterprise provisioning profile?

Comment: Are you sure it's the dylib that is the problem, and not the signing of the main executable?

Comment: Yes, its definitely the dylib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the mentioned Enterprise certificate appear under *Settings ➞ Profiles* on the iOS devices that experience the problem?

Is said Enterprise certificate available as a valid (signable) certificate on the Xcode installation where you package the final .ipa?

Do you use the same certificate for signing the dylibs and the app?

The standard way of pushing an Enterprise certificate to devices is to include it when packaging/archiving an app. Xcode *should* do this automatically - at least for the certificate used to sign the app itself.

You can extract an .ipa (rename to .zip) and look for a file called "embedded.mobileprovision" in the .app package.